# Vue as ES Module Build loses reactivity when I build component library using vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, es6-modules, rollup

I am currently working on a project and want to create several components, build them via vite and use them in another project using the Vue CDN hosted standalone version.

As mentioned on the website, I use Vue

```
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
     "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
     }
}
</script>
```

Then in this project, I use Vue with importmap ES Build, and import my generated vue components from my static path. I added another createVue, just to check if vue is reactive at all.
The second vue instance (#lala) is reactive, I can update the counter ref and see the results.

```
<div id="appvue"></div>

<div id="lala"> 
  <div @click="counter++">
    {{counter}}
   </div>
</div>
                            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/vue/style.css" type="text/css" />
                     
<script type="module">
    import { createApp, ref } from 'vue'
    import { MyComponent } from '/static/js/vue/index.js';
                    
    createApp(MyComponent).mount('#appvue')
              
    createApp({
        setup() {
            const counter = ref(0)
            return {
              counter
            }
        }
    }).mount('#lala');
</script>
```

Here comes the tricky part: I create my vue Components in my static dir:

MyComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    hallo
  <button @click="count++">Du hast {{ count }} mal geklickt</button>
  <div class="message">Hier ist die message: {{message}}</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <input v-model="text">
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
    setup()
    {
        const count = ref(0);
        const text = ref("ändere mich");

        const message = ref("hallo");

        return {
            count,
            message,
            text
        };
    }
};
</script>

<style>
div{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.message{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: mediumvioletred;
}
</style>
```

My main.ts file, which is the entry for vite:

```
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue"
export { MyComponent }
```

And finally my vite config, which should build my Lib:

```
import {fileURLToPath, URL} from "url"
import {defineConfig, loadEnv} from "vite"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

defineConfig(({ mode }) =>
{
    const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
    return {
        plugins: [vue()],
        root: "frontend",
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./frontend/src", import.meta.url))
            }
        },
        server: {
            port: 3000,
        },
        build: {
            lib: {
                entry: "./src/main.ts",
                formats: ["es", "cjs"],
                fileName: format => (format == "es" ? "index.js" : "index.cjs")
            },
            rollupOptions: {
                external: ["vue"],
                output: {
                    globals: {
                        vue: "Vue",
                    },
                },
            }
        },
        define: {
            "process.env": env
        },
        test: {
            globals: true,
            environment: "jsdom",
            reporters: "junit",
            outputFile: "../build/reports/vitest/vitest.xml"
        }
    }
})
```

So my problem is, the counter in the #lala div is reactive and counts up, the counter in the built Component is visible, but not updating at all. What could be the problem? Been stuck there since a while now and can't come up with a solution so that the built component is reactive.

Comment: The problem with reactivity is what's observed when there's more than 1 Vue copy. You' relying on window.Vue in one place but use Vue ESM in another.

Comment: so should i delete the globals: { vue: "Vue"} ? or what should I try?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect that you need to keep external and remove globals, can't say for sure if it's the only problem in your setup

Comment: I am still not able to interact with my Vue Components :(

Comment: Can you provide a simplified way to reproduce? Would benefit from debugging at this point. The comp could likely be static .js because that's what it's built to.

Comment: unfortuanetly, I cant provide a simplified version. The Error I get when I remove the global is: ERROR - [JSC_INVALID_MODULE_PATH] Invalid module path "vue" for resolution mode "BROWSER"
  1| import { ref as r, openBlock as a, createElementBlock as m, Fragment as _, createTextVNode as u, createElementVNode as s, toDisplayString as i, withDirectives as d, vModelText as p } from "vue";

Comment: At which point the error occurs, on component package build? It looks like this is google closure error, and it's unclear how it's related to the setup you posted (vite+rollup), as closure not a part of it